# Algorithms for the Antikythera Mechanism

Tags: algorithms

I am working on a little computer program, and i was wondering if any one knew of any collections of all the calculations done and their associated mathematical algorithms?

The algorithms dont have to be suitable for computers, i should be able to translate them. Any help would be great

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, can you give some example or elaborate perhaps?